# Is there a single noun for "value available at compile time"?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm working on an interpreter for some programming language.

The language uses many concepts, notably the concept of:

- "type" or "data type" (see [Wikipedia's *data type* page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type))
- "value", in the sense of "data to which a *type* is assigned"

The interpreter for the language runs through at least two phases (happening in this order):

1. compile time
2. run time

Currently, in the [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) of the code base of the interpreter that implements the "run time" phase, I have a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) named `Value` and a class named `Type`.

I am in the process of bringing the `Type` class back to the "compile time" phase, so that type checking is done at the "compile time" phase rather than at the "run time" phase (In other words I'm trying to recover from a bad design decision).

This implies that I also have to somehow bring a *bent* version of the `Value` class back to the "compile time" phase. More precisely, I have to create a new class that can:

- generate a `Value`
- infer the `Type` of the `Value` that can be generated

You could describe this concept as a "type-ascribed not-yet-evaluated value", or as a "value with a type", or as a "lazy value which type can be accessed without actually performing any run time operation".

[EDIT]

In other words, I'm trying to find a noun group for a **value** that is meant to be evaluated at **run time**, but which **type** is available at **compile time** without any computational cost.

[/EDIT]

So I'm now stuck, staring at my screen, looking for a miracle to find a way to name this concept. **I'm looking for a noun group with the least amount of characters in it that represents this concept.**

Here are some exemples of how the noun group would be used in an English sentence (as opposed to "in an identifier") like this:

> As you see here [points a line of code], I can infer the type of an expression by using a [the noun group] without even evaluating the expression.
>
> [The noun group] allows you to freely export some source code into as many different target languages as you'd like.

So far I came up with these names (each of them is followed by the reason it was dropped surrounded in parentheses):

> class ValueThatHasAType { ... }

(It's really verbose, despite representing pretty well the idea)

> class CompileTimeValueAndType { ... }

(It's really verbose, again, despite being really close to the concept I want)

> class Symbol { ... }

(accordingly to [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/symbol), "symbol" is a "*letter, character, sign of written communication*" (at the time I write this), but I'm trying to represent some sort of `Value`)

> class TypedLazyValue { ... }

(This is not really adapted: A `LegsArmsBodyHead` isn't a `Human`. In other words, `TypedLazyValue` is too broad)

I'm not really expecting a single noun to exist for this (since I searched a lot on google and I couldn't find an acceptable term in the terminology used in the fields of compilation and interpretation), but if there is one, then I'd really be pleased to hear about it.

Comment: How would you use the adjective in an English sentence (as opposed to in an identifier)?

Comment: @Lawrence I added two examples to clarify. Is my question clear enough now?

Comment: Why would the compilation phase need an adjective? Just so it could be made into a comparative or a superlative? Seems silly.

Comment: @tchrist Well I'm not super sure how to name better this question. Please read the description, I think you would get a better understanding of what I meant.

Comment: Trust me, I am intimately familar with compilation-vs-execution phases of interpreters. I still don't understand what you want. You seem to want words for identifiers in a program, but that's off-topic here. Perhaps your question should be on [programmers.se].

Comment: @tchrist Am I supposed to make `single-word-requests` on Software Engineering if they are about SE? If that's the case, then I wrongly though I could `single-word-request` any idea or concept. In the end, all of the compiler / interpreter context I put in the question has the only purpose of explaining the term / group of terms I'm looking for. Yes, I guess you need to know about SE to see what I'm looking for, but on another hand I'm not after software design.

Comment: Your examples seem to require noun phrases to replace the placeholder "[the noun group]", but the title asks for adjectives. Which are you after?

Comment: @Lawrence I was first asking for an adjective, then I realized I was after a noun, so I changed the content of the question but not the title. Should be fixed now

Comment: This question is better asked on a related SE site -- a well-defined and in-use term or expression may already exist as known to developers. Good Luck.

Comment: If an English language expert suggests a semantically suitable expression, how would you expect others in your domain to understand it correctly at first sight?

Comment: *Compile-time value* might work. But isn't a compile-time value just a constant (or constant expression)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow or SuperUser.

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree: see [stack overflow "on topic" guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [super user "on topic" guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If, so far, I found a noun group that satisfies me personally, then should I close this question, or rather should I answer my question? I'm afraid the answer would be extremely silly, so much that I think I should not have asked this in the first place...

Comment: Whatever, a value available at compile time is known as a "compile-time constant".

Comment: @HotLicks As I understand the idea of a "compile-time constant", I'm afraid it's not the case. to cite the content of my question: "_You could describe this concept as a "type-ascribed not-yet-evaluated value", or as a "value with a type", or as a "lazy value which type can be accessed without actually performing any run time operation"_". This implies I'm looking for a **value** that is meant to be evaluated at **run time**, but which **type** is available at **compile time** without any computational cost.

Comment: Based on the "names you've come up with so far" how about ***TypedValue*** and ***TypedConstant***?

Comment: @Jim _TypedValue_ is extremely close to the thing I was looking for, but _Typed**Value**_ does not express the fact that it is meant to be evaluated at run time. Yet, because of the lack of a better noun group for my particular case _so far_, this would work.

Answer (score 2):

You could call this a **declaration reference**.

If I understand you correctly, your language has lexical tokens that have a type property and a value property.

The token *123* for example has the type *integer* and a value that identifies a location in a table. As the compilation proceeds, the entry at that table location will change. Ultimately, it may contain a relative address in the memory of the execution system, which in turn may contain a binary coded number.

In the first stage of lexical analysis, there is no real way to identify the type, unless it has been previously *declared*.

The declaration can be *explicit*, as it is in C++, Java and similar arguments.

The declaration can also be *implicit* in various ways. For example, the assignment of a string constant to a variable can implicitly declare the variable to be a string. This may require more than a simple analysis however, since many languages allow upconversions, implicit casting and other programmer conveniences, which make anything other than a simple assignment difficult to parse.

In any case, if you want to determine the association between a lexical token and a type, some kind of association must have already been performed. At runtime this can sometimes be done by examining the value assigned at an earlier point in the execution. Prior to runtime, the association must be made by some kind of declaration.  Hence the term **declaration reference**.

**Edited to add:**

More generally, you could refer to the declaration as a **type binding**, in the same way that an *assignment* is a *value binding*. However, *declaration* might be more clearly seen as something that happens at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds kind of like a Constant, though that may be something different or I misunderstood your intent, or Invariant, or Fixed class.

Comment: My question was not clear when you answered. I added a rephrasing below the concept I'm looking for: a "_**value** that is meant to be evaluated at **run time**, but which **type** is available at **compile time** without any computational cost_".